# How do I force Google Photos app to refresh?

Tags: sync, google-photos

I deleted some images on photos.google.com but the Photos app on my phone doesn't reflect these changes and still show the images. How do I force the app to refresh? I already tried clearing cache but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the sync on for your Google account. If it still does not update, re-install the app, that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes just dragging down just below the notification bar and releasing will give the circling "I'm refreshing" arrows and start the sync.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one or more of the following:

1. restart the app.
2. sign out and sign in your google account again; or, switch to other account and switch back.
3. restart you phone.
4. cut off network connection and reconnect it.
5. clear drive database.